# SQL Combine 2 Rows at a Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table of keywords that I want to make 2 word combinations of while keeping in sequential order (i.e. I don't want every 2 word combo, just when they are before or after one another).

I can make this work with a `WHILE` loop, but the query is bulky and not optimal since I need to use this within a larger query.  My query below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    RowNum INT
    ,Keyword VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT #Temp
VALUES
(1, 'Apple'),
(2, 'Flavored'),
(3, 'Ice'),
(4, 'Tea')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Final') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Final

CREATE TABLE #Final
(
    Combined VARCHAR(101)
)

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @kw1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @kw2 VARCHAR(50)

SET @i = 2

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE RowNum = @i)
BEGIN

    SET @kw1 = (SELECT Keyword FROM #Temp WHERE RowNum = @i - 1)
    SET @kw2 = (SELECT Keyword FROM #Temp WHERE RowNum = @i)

    INSERT #Final
    SELECT @kw1 + ' ' + @kw2

    SET @i = @i + 1

END

SELECT * FROM #Final
```

Does anyone know of a smarter/more efficient way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with `LEAD` as the below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        T.Keyword + ' ' + LEAD(T.Keyword) OVER (ORDER BY RowNum) Result
    FROM #Temp T
) A
WHERE
    A.Result IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Nailed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following

```
insert into #Final(Combined)
select Keyword + ' ' + Lag(Keyword,1,null) over (order by RowNum)
from #Temp
where RowNum>=2
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This one returned `NULL` for the first row, but I can see how it an be tweaked to work.  Thanks Hadi!

Answer (score 1):

Your code implies rownum column has no gaps. Then you can use plain JOIN on any Sql Server version I can remember.

```
select t1.Keyword + ' '+ t2.Keyword
from #temp t1
join #temp t2 on t2.RowNum = t1.RowNum +1
```

Comment: Also a valid answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script if you are using `sql 2012` or higher version.

```
;WITH cte_1
as
(SELECT Keyword+' '+LEAD(Keyword) OVER(ORDER BY RowNum) Combined
FROM #temp ) 
SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE Combined is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do it simply by using LEFT JOIN with the same table, ultimiately we have to use RowNum

```
SELECT CONCAT(t2.Keyword, ' ', t1.Keyword) KeyWords
FROM #temp t1
LEFT JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.RowNum = t2.RowNum+1
WHERE t2.Keyword IS NOT NULL
```